# Comment traduire « freak » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, registre-familier

Le dictionnaire donne « monstre » et « phénomène » pour la traduction mais je trouve ces termes excessifs dans la phrase « *You're such a freak* ».

En français, on dit parfois « tu es un cas » mais je me demande si cela peut se dire dans ce cas.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Tu ne donne pas trop de détails sur le contexte qui t'intéresse, mais d'après ton exemple, il semble clair que tu fais référence à l'usage **contemporain** du mot (dérivé, mais très différent, de l'utilisation qui en était faite dans les années 30 et auparavant): un terme à l'origine plutôt péjoratif, mais largement réapproprié pour signifier "hors-norme" (dans un sens positif, ou en tout cas fièrement assumé).

Je pense que tous les exemples donnés jusqu'à présent sont corrects, mais extrêmement liés à leur époque: "un cas" ou "givré" ne seraient probablement pas utilisés par l'équivalent français des couches démographiques qui utilisent "freak" en anglais ("énergumène", encore moins)...

"Taré" ou "cinglé" me semblent parmi les plus proches, il y aussi [les étonnamment contemporains] "malade" ou "fou": "C'est un malade/fou!"... Mais aucun ne couvre toutes les nuances (négatives *et* positives) du terme anglais. J'ai vu à de nombreuses reprises le terme anglais utilisé tel quel sur des sites francophones (dans un contexte plutôt familier, cosmopolite et/ou "jeune", cela dit), signe qu'il n'existe peut-être pas d'équivalent parfait...

**Ajout:** "zarb'" (dérivé verlan de "bizarre"), suggéré par Sylvain me semble très proche, mais comme il le fait remarquer: sans doute trop daté (et avec ce genre de mot, quelques années suffisent à faire la différence entre "authentique jeune branché" et "vieux croûton qui veut faire jeune"). Mais du coup ça m'a fait penser au nettement moins branché (mais du coup aussi moins daté): "tordu". Même si ça ne reflète pas la fraîcheur de langage d'un mot tel que "freak", dire à quelqu'un "t'es un tordu!" aurait plus ou moins la même nuance à la fois hors-norme et un peu admirative...

Il y a aussi la nuance sexuelle de "freak": pas seulement au sens de [la promiscuité sexuelle](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QYHxGBH6o4M), mais dans le sens d'un comportement général *et* sexuel "hors-norme" (fétichiste, gay...). Dans ce cas là, peut-être: "T'es un[e] vrai[e] vicieu[x/se]/obsédé[e]"?

**Note:** Même si je ne pense pas que ce soit le sens qui t'intéresse, il y aussi l'utilisation de "freak" comme synonyme pour "fan de" (ex.: "movie freak", "music freak" etc.). Dans ce cas, je pense que c'est plus facile à traduire, en utilisant par exemple (du moins au plus familier): "fou/dingue/taré de..."

Comment: Et en passant... peut-être que nos amis québécois peuvent confirmer: il me semble que l'utilisation du mot "freak" tel quel est assez courant en parler moderne dans la Belle Province (peut-être avec une nuance différente, néanmoins).

Comment: Même s'il a déjà été cité au milieu d'énumérations dans les réponses de Dave et Joubarc, je me permets d'insister sur la pertinence de **taré**. Comme l'anglais *freak*, il a culturellement glissé d'un emploi péjoratif à un emploi nettement plus positif ou assumé.

Answer (score 7):

*Tu es un cas* me paraît approprié, ou éventuellement *Tu es cinglé*.

Answer (score 6):

Something like *'T'es un dingue.'*?

Comment: Ou *t'es dingue* qui me paraît plus naturel.

Comment: T'es un guedin ! T'es un ouf ! Je trouve que le "un" met de l'emphase.

Answer (score 4):

Je rajouterais "T'es vraiment déjanté!".
Si la personne en question est absente "Il est vraiment space!".
Malade, ouf et déviant pourraient également tous convenir selon le contexte.

Answer (score 3):

"T'es zarb" ? Mais c'est un peu daté et très familier.

Je rajoute pour le plaisir le fameux "t'es fou dans ta tête"...

Comment: *You're such a freak* est familier.

Answer (score 3):

- Tu n'es pas tout juste.
- Tu n'es pas bien.
- Tu es givré/taré.

Answer (score 3):

« Allumé », comme dans « il est complètement allumé », « T'es vraiment allumé ».

Peut-être « grave » ou « gravos », « T'es grave ! », « C'est gravos ».

Je repense aussi à « zazou ».

Comment: +1 pour "T'es grave!"

Answer (score 2):

> **Énergumène**
>
> - Personne qu'agite un enthousiasme déréglé ou une vive passion. *Crier, s'agiter comme un énergumène.*
> - *Par hyperbole.* Homme qui pousse ses raisonnements ou ses assertions jusqu'à la folie.

(Les définitions sont celles du Littré.)

Comment: C'est correct, mais ca ne s'emploie pas beaucoup dans la vie de tous les jours.

Answer (score 2):

Au Québec, j'opterais plutôt pour "t'es [donc ben] capoté". Je crois que "malade" pourrait aussi faire l'affaire. Si on parle plutôt d'un fan, ce serait "maniaque de".

Pour répondre au commentaire de Dave, je n'ai personnellement jamais entendu "freak" comme tel dans ce sens-là. (Cependant, nous utilisons "Jesus freak" et "control freak". "C'est freak" est un diminutif de "c'est freakant", c.-à-d. c'est épeurant, ça donne la chair de poule.)

Comment: Où siègent les gallinacées...

Comment: J'aurai au moins appris le verbe _[épeurer](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A9peurant)_

Comment: En fait, nous utilisons "épeurant" seulement comme adjectif. Je ne savais pas qu'il y avait un verbe!

Answer (score 1):

Québécois ici, mon choix de traduction en parlant d'une personne serait : obsédé.
Comme dans : tu es freak de quelque chose, exemple control freak.
Maniaque est bon aussi.

Si on parle d'un objet ou évènement qui est freak, on est alors dans le sens de angoissant, effrayant (épeurant), exemple freak show.

Complément d'informations, au Québec les mots cinglé, taré, dingue, zarbi ne sont jamais utilisés.

Comment: Ton dernier propos est exagéré à mon avis ; le mot _cinglé_ est certainement employé et l'exemple sur [Usito](https://usito.usherbrooke.ca/d%C3%A9finitions/cingl%C3%A9) provient d'une autrice québécoise. J'ai déjà employé _taré_, les deux autres non. La langue n'est peut-être pas aussi uniforme que tu le crois...